# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
    var result = from lr in _db.LeaveRequest  
                 join th in _db.TotalHourslu    
                 on lr.TotalHoursEffect 
                 equals th.Minutesselect 
                     new {lr.TotalHoursEffect, th.Minutes, tr.Display};
```

ERROR:  in  **new**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your `select`; try this:

```
var result = from lr in _db.LeaveRequest  
             join th in _db.TotalHourslu    
               on lr.TotalHoursEffect equals th.Minutesselect 
             select new {lr.TotalHoursEffect, th.Minutes, tr.Display};
```